# my phone cannot play stereo over 3.5mm headphone jack

Tags: audio, headphones, google-play-games

recently I tried to run android games on my laptop in *Gameloop* emulator (shooter games in general). after playing a couple of minutes in ***PUBG Mobile*** with the same headphone on, I noticed that the audio direction and footstep sound are far more clear and accurate than what it sounds on my mobile

- I have a non-rooted Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro with the latest MIUI 12 on it.
- and a headphone I purchased from a local store.

I saw [**this question**](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160385/how-to-play-5-1-audio-direct-to-speakers) on this site, and if I'm not wrong, it says that I cannot play more than 2 channel audio on a 3.5mm headphone jack! But since I was able to hear more accurately on my pc with the same 3.5mm audio jack(aux), I am thinking that the android was the problem.

Is there something I can change on my phone to make it output sounds like my pc, or even make it a little more accurate?

**PS:** another thing I want to mention is, my mobile doesn't even split left or right channel while playing surround videos on youtube. I cannot tell if the sound is completely from the left channel or right because both sides of the headphone play the same sound.

thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick fix for this issue, I think that every Xiaomi phone that's on MIUI12 can do the same step, the steps are:

on your phone go to...

> Settings ->   Additional Settings ->   Accessibility-> [scroll down] Mono Audio(turn off this)

on my phone, **Mono Audio** was (**ON**) by default, and that is the reason that your phone will get ridiculously loud *(both on your headphone and speakers)* and not accurate for sound direction while gaming or watching movies, notice if you *Disable* **Mono Audio** your over-all Sounds volume will decrease a by half, and AFAIK this is because your Audio volume will combine while on Mono.

hope that helps. thanks